# How to calculate BIC and AIC for a gmm model in #R using #plm?

Tags: panel-data, aic, bic, generalized-moments

I originally posted this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46186527/how-to-calculate-bic-and-aic-for-a-gmm-model-in-r-using-plm). But I think it is better suited for here.

I am running `Generalized Method of Moments (GMM) Estimation for Panel Data` in `R` using the `plm`. I have set of valid instruments, and I would like to select one using `BIC-GMM` or `AIC-GMM` criteria for instance. However, when I tried to compute using the standard `R` command `AIC`, but shows an error. I would like to compute a function from scratch, but I don't know which is the right formula for the GMM context. I'm using the `differenced` transformation, which basically is the [Arrellano and Bond, (1991)](https://academic.oup.com/restud/article-abstract/58/2/277/1563354) estimator.

```
library('plm')
plm.gmm <-
  pgmm(
  dynformula(as.formula(model), lg),
  data = pdata,
  effect = 'twoway',
  model = 'twostep',
  transformation = 'd',
  gmm.inst = Z[[i]],
  lag.gmm =  c(lg.gmm[[i]][[1]], lg.gmm[[i]][[2]])
  )
AIC(plm.gmm, k=2)
Error in UseMethod("logLik") : 
  no applicable method for 'logLik' applied to an object of class "c('pgmm', 'panelmodel')"
```

In this [website](http://pages.pomona.edu/~jsh04747/courses/math158/multlin4.pdf) I found the following formula:
$$AIC= N + SSE*\log{(k*\pi)} + N*\log{(SSE/N)} + k * (1+1)$$

- N=Number of observations.
- SSE=Sum of squared residuals.
- k=Penalty   per parameter.

I have two questions, can I use this formula in the context of `GMM panel estimation`, and what it's the intuition behind `(1+1)` term.

Comment: how do you get the `plm.gmm` object?

Comment: What do you mean by GMM? Gaussian mixture models?

Comment: Hi – DataD'oh, I changed a bit my question to reply to your comments.

Comment: you may want to check this article: Andrews, Donald WK. "Consistent moment selection procedures for generalized method of moments estimation." Econometrica 67, no. 3 (1999): 543-563.